# Image not loading on "beforeunload" event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using "beforeunload" event in Jquery for the purpose of show loading icon when the page is unloading.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (event) {

        $('body').html('<div class="modal" style="display:block;background-color:green !important;" id="spinning1"><div class="center"> <img alt="Loading..." src="~/images/AjaxLoader.gif" /> </div> </div>');
    });
```

The particular image is not loading when i am using '~/images/AjaxLoader.gif' or '../images/AjaxLoader.gif' or 'images/AjaxLoader.gif' even though image is available in correct location.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: try `'unload'` instead of `'beforeunload'`

Comment: You are not blocking the event with the default user prompt ? Why would the browser render this since it has to close the page anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example for loading image while page loading.

**Html**

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('images/pageLoader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
    opacity: .8;
}
```

**Script**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

See [working example](http://demos.codexworld.com/display-loading-image-while-page-loads-jquery-css/) or you can [download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/HN9EepuoHHJmR289G3YKEv4qAhlXGznZuzbatddAZucPYYg12PsyaU3LBSNwK7rV/file?dl=1) sample code . I have found it [here](http://www.codexworld.com/display-loading-image-while-page-loads-jquery-css/)